# How to tell if an application is playing sound

Tags: audio

For an application playing sound , how can I tell when the sound has stopped so to speak
Say I have a bunch of URL's that link to a music on the web
and I want after a song has been played to advance to the next one ( yes playlists )
can I get some sort of audio event ( vista or even win7 specific ok)that lets me know when an application stops playing sound

Comment: wouldn't this depend on your player API?  Or are you spawning an external program or invoking the windows shell to play the audio?

Comment: embedding the explorer control so essentially whatever the website is using flash windows media etc

Answer (score 0):

That's not reliable since other programs may be playing sound at the time your song ends. Determine the length of each song programmatically as you download them.

Comment: length may be possible BUT other sound should not matter first for arguments sake lets assume its not an issue ie I make sure only my app is playing sound. however in Windows vista onwards I notice that the volume mixer lets you set process level volume levels and process level muting so I have to believe there is process level ability to know if a process is not playing sound
I could be wrong though

Comment: sure, but do you really want to be listening repeatedly when you can easily access the length of each song to know when to move to the next?